# OpenAL, alcOpenDevice blocking

Tags: c++, initialization, freeze, openal

I've been trying to add sound into a program of mine using OpenAL, but it seems like the call to initialise OpenAL freeze when calling `alcOpenDevice(NULL);`. I've been looking on the internet for a solution to this issue, i've even tried to reinstall the OpenAL library, but nothing seems to work.

```
ALCdevice* dev = NULL;
ALCcontext* ctx = NULL;
dev = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
ctx = alcCreateContext(dev, NULL);
alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You mean this call never returns? Can you run it in debugger and look where it stalls?

Comment: @keltar for me it stalls somewhere in a different thread in system libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving out defining the device name, it works this way :

```
const char * devicename = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);

dev  = alcOpenDevice(devicename);
```

Here is a simple c language usage of OpenAL - it populates a buffer then renders the sound :

```
https://github.com/scottstensland/openal_synth_play
```

Once you go beyond a very simple usage, assure you fork off a thread dedicated to your OpenAL logic otherwise you will not get sound since you'll be starving the openal

Comment: NULL is actually quite ok for selecting default device.